# Pivot point changing from median point to individual origins when rotating

Tags: modeling

I select multiple objects, I start rotating them with Median pivot point selected, I write a numerical value to rotate them precisely (e.g. 90 degrees), BUT what happens is that Blender rotate the selected objects with Individual origins pivot pont instead of Median pivot point.

Essentially, if I simply rotate multiple objects manually, with median pivot point selected, everything works fine, BUT if I instead write a numerical value while rotating, for whatever reason, the pivot point "method" changes from median pivot point to individual origins.

Hope it's clear.

Comment: Hello, it is either a bug or you have a conflicting keymap (I don't think it is even possible to change origin setting when the rotation already started). What version are you using ?

Comment: I'm using 2.91. How can I check if there's a conflicting keymap?